# r move duplicates by ignoring values in one column

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates

I am trying to remove duplicates from my dataset that have similar values in a subset of column and ignoring values in one column. For example if this is my dataset

```
ID Date        SampleID  Time(GMT)   Salinity Density   Phosphate
1  24/06/2002  1st-U2    1000        33.855             0.01
1  24/06/2002  1st-U6    1000        33.855             0.01
2  01/07/2002  F150      1000        33.104  24.873     0.06
2  01/07/2002  F151      1000        33.104  24.873     0.06
3  08/07/2002  11/11     1000        33.609  25.248     0.01
3  08/07/2002  11/12     1000        33.609  25.248     0.01
4  15/07/2002  SP567-4   1000        34.507  26.199     0.01
5  22/07/2002  3PM28F1   1000        33.792  25.269     0.08
5  22/07/2002  3PM28F2   1000        33.792  25.269     0.08
6  29/07/2002            1000        34.09   25.642     0.02
```

How do I remove duplicates by ignoring values in Column `SampleID`

Expecting dataset like this.

```
ID Date        SampleID  Time(GMT)   Salinity Density   Phosphate
1  24/06/2002  1st-U2    1000        33.855             0.01
2  01/07/2002  F150      1000        33.104  24.873     0.06
3  08/07/2002  11/11     1000        33.609  25.248     0.01
4  15/07/2002  SP567-4   1000        34.507  26.199     0.01
5  22/07/2002  3PM28F1   1000        33.792  25.269     0.08
6  29/07/2002            1000        34.09   25.642     0.02
```

Any advise is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In base R:

```r
df[!duplicated(df$ID),]
#>    ID       Date SampleID Time.GMT. Salinity Density Phosphate
#> 1   1 24/06/2002   1st-U2      1000   33.855      NA      0.01
#> 3   2 01/07/2002     F150      1000   33.104  24.873      0.06
#> 5   3 08/07/2002    11/11      1000   33.609  25.248      0.01
#> 7   4 15/07/2002  SP567-4      1000   34.507  26.199      0.01
#> 8   5 22/07/2002  3PM28F1      1000   33.792  25.269      0.08
#> 10  6 29/07/2002     <NA>      1000   34.090  25.642      0.02
```

A tidyverse approach would be

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize_all(first)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 7
#>      ID Date       SampleID Time.GMT. Salinity Density Phosphate
#>   <int> <chr>      <chr>        <int>    <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1     1 24/06/2002 1st-U2        1000     33.9    NA        0.01
#> 2     2 01/07/2002 F150          1000     33.1    24.9      0.06
#> 3     3 08/07/2002 11/11         1000     33.6    25.2      0.01
#> 4     4 15/07/2002 SP567-4       1000     34.5    26.2      0.01
#> 5     5 22/07/2002 3PM28F1       1000     33.8    25.3      0.08
#> 6     6 29/07/2002 <NA>          1000     34.1    25.6      0.02
```

---

**Question data in reproducible format**

```r
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L), 
    Date = c("24/06/2002", "24/06/2002", "01/07/2002", "01/07/2002", 
    "08/07/2002", "08/07/2002", "15/07/2002", "22/07/2002", "22/07/2002", 
    "29/07/2002"), SampleID = c("1st-U2", "1st-U6", "F150", "F151", 
    "11/11", "11/12", "SP567-4", "3PM28F1", "3PM28F2", NA), Time.GMT. = c(1000L, 
    1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L
    ), Salinity = c(33.855, 33.855, 33.104, 33.104, 33.609, 33.609, 
    34.507, 33.792, 33.792, 34.09), Density = c(NA, NA, 24.873, 
    24.873, 25.248, 25.248, 26.199, 25.269, 25.269, 25.642), 
    Phosphate = c(0.01, 0.01, 0.06, 0.06, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.08, 
    0.08, 0.02)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L
))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>